# How do I return an object from within a nested function? Higher order functions

Tags: javascript

I'm using an EJS template to render a page. The data I'm using to render the page is an object pulled from a Firebase data store.

The method accessing the data store is a property of a `utils` object. The data is pulled from Firebase and each element in the data store added to the `box` array.

The result of `pullFromFirebase()` is set to a `data` variable defined in another js file. I want the box of objects returned by Firebase available to `data`. `data` will ultimately be fed into the render method for my template.

Attempts to access `utils.box` via the `data` variable return `undefined` when the page loads. I know `box` contains the elements from Firebase; if I `console.log(box);` after the `for` loop in `pullFromFirebase`, the box contents are returned.

Similarly, if `pullFromFirebase` is called from the console with `utils.pullFromFirebase();` the contents of `box` are also returned. Calls to `data();` from the console also return `box`.

**How do I access the object returned from `pullFromFirebase` programmatically via `data();`?**

```
// file1.js
var db = new Firebase('firebaseURL');
var data = utils.pullFromFirebase(); // data(); returns 'undefined'


// file2.js
var utils = { 
    pullFromFirebase: function () {

        db.on("value", function(snapshot) {
            var notebook = snapshot.val(); 
            var box = [];

            for (list in notebook) {
                box.push(notebook[list]);
            }
            utils.box = box;
        });

        return utils.box; 
    }
};
```

Any other properties of the `utils` return successfully. Only the `box` object is not returned. If I `console.dir(utils);` I see `box` as a property of `utils` along with its values. So I when I can see `box` I can't touch `box`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `utils.pullFromFirebase` is making an asynchronous call to the database, it should accept at least a callback function to do something useful with the returned values in `box`.

```
//file1.js
var db = new Firebase('firebaseURL'), data;
utils.pullFromFirebase(
    function (result) {
        data = result; /* When the call to the database returns, data variable is set to the results of that call. */
    });


//file2.js
var utils = {
    pullFromFirebase: function (callback) {
        db.on("value", function(snapshot) {
            var notebook = snapshot.val();
            var box = [];
            for (list in notebook) {
                box.push(notebook[list]);
            }
            utils.box = box;
            callback(box); /* Callback function is called with the database results. */
        });
    }
};
```